# Touchstart, -end and -move events on a View containing a ListView

Tags: ios, listview, appcelerator, gesture

I have basically this layout:

```
<Window>
  <View id="header" />
  <View id="content">
    <ListView />  
  </View>
</Window>
```

now what i want is to animate the **header** view while i drag the ListView. I tried setting a `touchstart` `touchend` and `touchmove` event on the **content**. I also need ListView to be clickable...

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`touchStart` is not an event that is supported by the `ListView`. So you will not be receiving that event from the listview at all.

You can look at the [documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ListView) to see what events are supported by ListView.

Because your ListView is nested inside the view doesn't mean you'll get events of the parent view. Because ListView uses your touchInput only the events supported by the ListView will be triggered.

There are other events you can use for the ListView that might be useful like `scrollStart`.

Comment: I figured. but since it works on android, I was thinking I might be missing something. On android I can listen to `touch-` events on the `View`, while having all the events of `ListView`